# Secure connection of .net winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, security

I am developing an .net Winforms application and I need to secure the connection to the sql server 2008 database. I plan to create a webservice as a middle tier that will handle the authentication and that will provide data manipulation. Is there a better way to go with? Does .net have components or tools for that? What is the best technique?
Any info would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: When you say "secure" what are you trying to accomplish? Encrypt the SQL connection?

Comment: Well I want to make database inaccessible to everyone, because if I store a connection string in app.config then you can easily connect to the db. As Brian and KeithS mentioned It seems that WPF can handle it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define "secure". Obviously you wish to restrict access to data to users who really need that data. However, more information about the architecture is needed; is this an in-house app that will only ever be used inside a (secured) LAN, VPN or hosted environment? Or is this an app used on computers you do not control, that will transmit data over the Internet? How much security you need depends on what types of users will be using the software, from where, and how sensitive the data is.

MSS has pretty good security built-in. You can tie SQL users to Windows domain accounts, you can restrict "securables" (tables, views, SPs, etc) in myriad ways based on user or role, etc etc. I would first look at those capabilities, and seriously consider taking advantage of them in your security plan. One SQL user defined for use by any user of a particular piece of software, which has the permissions to do anything the software may require, is simple, common, and highly insecure.

If that's not good enough, or you want to fully abstract your data layer (for instance, if you need the software to be able to be pointed at any DB type from MSS to Oracle to MySql), then it might be a good idea to implement a Repository model with a service proxy. Like Brian, I encourage you to have a look at WCF. A WCF service is highly configurable, and can provide for independent authentication and for encryption. A well-designed WCF service will be very secure indeed.

Behind the service, you can implement a Repository pattern, which abstracts the details of how data is retrieved from the data store and exposes simple methods that return objects containing the data you want in a ready-to-use form. Now, your service methods will just map 1:1 to Repository methods, possibly with some translation to DataContract-serializable objects instead of the richer domain model available on either side of the service.

Comment: Good points Keith, and you can use a combination of some of these too; for instance, WCF can pass your Windows credentials to the database, to check against an account, tied to a Windows credential.

Comment: True, but that starts becoming redundant; using Windows-integrated SQL users requires the person logging in to be on the same Windows domain; that in turn usually requires being inside the LAN or on a VPN, which both should be well-secured from unauthorized access. Putting another layer of authentication and encryption inside a secured environment will lower performance while not really adding any security (if you're inside the LAN, you can just go around the WCF service to get into the DB with your Windows user or the one you hacked).

Comment: True, but you could host the WCF service on a different machine, use a white list to only allow the WCF machine to communicate with the database, and only allow the WCF service to access the database, forcing users to use WCF as the pass-through, even the most secure environments/LAN's can be broken into; we don't know how paranoid his security requirements are, or the type of data being handled. Sometimes a trade-off in performance is worth the extra .01% chance, sometimes it's not.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. The application will run on VPN network and it has sensitive data, the application is for casino management so it might be interesting for somebody to hack into:) Windows domain accounts are not available, so I prefer users and roles entered in the db for authentication and application usage restriction. I have not used the WCF before, maybe somebody knows some good tutorial or examples to begin?

Comment: Well even more a reason for security, keep in mind, one principle of highly secure applications is reducing the number of gates/access points into one place. For instance, as I stated above, if you restrict the database to only communicate with the WCF machine, and no one else; someone has to compromise that machine, to gain access to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at building a service tier, using WCF? WCF can bring a whole new layer of abstraction and security from the actual physical database.

WCF also allows you to use more secure bindings than a traditional web service allows, with built-in logging.

Also, check out this book sometime if you want a really good read on .NET Security:

- [The .NET Developer's Guide to Windows Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321228359) by Keith Brown

Comment: No I haven't used the WCF before, thanks I will try to use it